# Error en pip (Python3, Linux)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

estoy aprendiendo a como crear paquetes distribuibles con Python, e creado uno y ahora quiero instalarlo en mi propio pc con linux. Antes no me dejaba crear el setup porque no tenía instalado setuptools, lo instalé e hice el setup. Después instalé pip y puse en la terminal: pip install Nombredelpaquete y me aparece esto:

```
Processing ./Paquetecalculos-1.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: Paquetecalculos
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Paquetecalculos ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-T47Rmq-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp2AN5hspip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for Paquetecalculos
  Running setup.py clean for Paquetecalculos
Failed to build Paquetecalculos
Installing collected packages: Paquetecalculos
  Running setup.py install for Paquetecalculos ... done
Successfully installed Paquetecalculos-1.0
```

¿Alguien sabe lo que pasa?

Comment: Prueba instalar el paquete `wheel` con `pip install wheel` a ver si se soluciona.

Comment: Si a funcionado! ¿Pero para que servie el paquete wheel?

Comment: El wheel es el nuevo estándar para empaquetar código, si necesitas generar un paquete wheel (bdist_wheel hace eso) necesitas instalar este paquete.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!!